# Outer Variable Access in PHP Class

Tags: php, oop, class, global-variables, data-access

Consider the following situation

file: ./include/functions/table-config.php
containing: `.
.
$tablePages = 'orweb_pages';
.
.`

file: ./include/classes/uri-resolve.php
containing: `class URIResolve {
.
.
$category = null ;
.
.
function process_uri() {
...
    $this->category = $tablePages;
...
}
.
.
}`

file: ./settings.php
containing: `.
.
require_once(ABSPATH.INC.FUNC.'/table-config.php');
require_once(ABSPATH.INC.CLASS.'/uri-resolve.php');
.
.`

Will this work. I mean will the access to $tablePages from process_uri() be acceptable or will it give erronous results.

Please suggest corrections or workarounds if error might occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a global (not recommended), a constant or a singleton configuration class.

Simply including

```
$tablePages = 'orweb_pages';
```

will give your variable local scope so it won't be visible inside other classes. If you use a constant:

```
define('TABLE_PAGES', 'orweb_pages');
```

TABLE_PAGES will be available for read access throughout the application regardless of scope.

The advantage of a constant over a global variable is that you dont have to worry about it being overridden in other areas of the application.

Comment: do constants necessarily have to be full Caps or is it just a programming practice to avoid any commonplace identifier clashes?

Comment: is the scope problem true for functions defined outside the class also?

Comment: no, functions declared outside a class are in the global namespace

Answer (score 9):

Use the [global keyword](http://se.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

In the file where you're assigning the value.

```
global $tablePages;
$tablePages = 'orweb_pages';
```

And in the other file:

```
class URIResolve {
  var $category;
  function process_uri() {
    global $tablePages;
    $this->category = $tablePages;
  }
}
```

Also, all global variables are available in the `$GLOBALS` array (which itself is a superglobal), so you can access the global variable anywhere without using the global keyword by doing something like this:

```
$my_value = $GLOBALS['tablePages'];
```

This also serves to make it harder to accidentally overwrite the value of the global. In the former example, any changes you made to `$tablePages` would change the global variable. Many a security bug has been created by having a global `$user` and overwriting it with a more powerful user's information.

Another, even safer approach is to provide the variable in the constructor to URIResolve:

```
class URIResolve {
  var $category;

  function __construct ($tablePages) {
    $this->category= $tablePages;
  }

  function process_uri() {
    // Now you can access table pages here as an variable instance
  }
}

// This would then be used as:
new URIResolve($tablePages);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Doubts: I will have to manually declare $GLOBALS['tablePages'] = 'tablePages'; right?

Comment: I like the last tip to pass to the constructor. Important. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 //Use variable php : $GLOBALS in __construct
 $x = "Example variable outer class";

class ExampleClass{
    public $variables; 
  function __construct()
  {
    $this->variables = $GLOBALS; //get all variables from $GLOBALS
  }
    // example get value var 
  public function UseVar(){
   echo $this->variables['x']; // return Example variable outer class
  }
    // example set value var
  public function setVar(){
    $this->variables['x'] = 100;
  } 
}
echo $x // return Example variable outer class;

$Example = new ExampleClass();
$Example->UseVar(); // return Example variable outer class
$Example->setVar(); // $x = 100;

// or use attr variables 
echo $Example->variables['x']; // 100
$Example->variables['x'] = "Hiii"; 
?>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more useful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do.